# Optimizing MySQL self-join query

Tags: mysql

I have following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(a1.actor) 
FROM actions a1 
JOIN actions a2 ON a1.ip = a2.ip 
WHERE a2.actor = 143 
AND a2.ip != '0.0.0.0' 
AND a2.ip != '' 
AND a2.actor != a1.actor 
AND a1.actor != 0
```

This is the explain of the query:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------+---------+---------+------------------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys    | key     | key_len | ref              | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------+---------+---------+------------------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a2    | range | actor,ip,actorIp | actorIp | 66      | NULL             | 3800 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a1    | ref   | ip               | ip      | 62      | formabilio.a2.ip |   11 | Using where              |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------+---------+---------+------------------+------+--------------------------+
```

Even if from this it doesn't seem a problematic query, in my machine it takes more or less 69 seconds with MyIsam and 56 seconds in InnoDB. The table has more or less 1 thousand records. As you can see from the explain I have indeces both on the actor column, on the ip column and even on both columns. I have mysql version 5.5.35.

Do you have any idea on why this query takes so long? How can I optimize it?

Comment: How long does it take without the all ip where conditions?

Comment: @DKasipovic without all the AND conditions it takes 1 minute and 19 seconds

Comment: Is that a local server or are you sending over network? Also, I said without the `ip` conditions, you can leave the `a2.actor` condition.

Comment: it is a local server. Without ip conditions is 1 minute 7 seconds

Comment: Could you please try the following query:

    SELECT DISTINCT(a1.actor) 
    FROM actions a2
    JOIN actions a1 ON a1.ip = a2.ip 
    WHERE a2.actor = 143 
    AND a2.ip != '0.0.0.0' 
    AND a2.ip != '' 
    AND a2.actor != a1.actor 
    AND a1.actor != 0

Comment: @TheChaos I can't spot a big bifference between mine and your query... in fact it takes the same time

Comment: ok, thanks marcosh for trying... is there any chance in getting an sqlfiddle with some test data from you?

Answer (score 0):

TABLE SCAN is doing in each record of the table actions.

According to this tutorial:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-self-join/

```
SELECT DISTINCT(a1.actor)
FROM actions a1
INNER JOIN actions a2 
ON a1.ip = a2.ip AND
   a1.actor <> a2.actor
WHERE a2.actor = 143 
AND a2.ip <> '0.0.0.0' 
AND a2.ip <> ''
AND a1.actor <> 0
```

Comment: I can't see any improvement using your query

Answer (score -1):

try this( if you didnt already do this ) ... the commands below should create indexes on the join-field and some where-conditions

```
CREATE INDEX _actions_ip ON actions( ip );
CREATE INDEX _actions_actor ON actions( actor );
```

Comment: as I said, "I have indeces both on the actor column, on the ip column and even on both columns"